# Write Partition with Date column Java-Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hdfs

I'm Using Java-Spark.

I'm trying to write to Hive table by date partition column,
What I'm trying is:

```
Dataset<Row> ds = dataframe.select(cols).withColumn("load_date", function.lit("08.07.2018").cast("date"));
ds.write().mode(mode).partitionBy("load_date").save(hdfsDirectory);
```

After I'm running the lines below I see in hdfs the following directory:

```
/load_date=__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__
```

That meaning on null value.

So how can I write partition by date?

Thanks.

Comment: If you use `cast("date")` you need to format the date correctly. Try "2018-08-07" and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier way is to use the following function

`from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2016/06/01','yyyy/MM/dd'),'yyyyMMdd')`

I prefer to use spark sql to achieve this

```
ds.createOrUpdateTempTable("tempTable")
val dsWithLoadDate = spark.sql("select *, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2016/06/01','yyyy/MM/dd'),'yyyyMMdd') as load_date from tempTable")
```

`dsWithLoadDate.write().mode(mode).partitionBy("load_date").save(hdfsDirectory);`

Answer (score 1):

To use `cast` date has to be in a standard form (year-month-day)

```
Dataset<Row> ds = dataframe.select(cols).withColumn("load_date", function.lit("2018-07-08").cast("date"));
```

Otherwise use `o.a.s.sql.functions.to_date` function and provide format compatible with [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: And If i want with diffrent format? yyyyMMdd ? Can I do it?